# Multi-line print statements with variables: Python 2 versus Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, variables, printing, syntax, python-2.x

I'm learning Python from Zed A. Shaw's *Learn Python the Hard Way*, and the book strongly recommends Python 2 rather than Python 3. So far, however, I've been doing it in Python 3 (so as to learn the differences between the two versions). The following code in exercise 8,

```
formatter = "%r %r %r %r"

...

print(formatter % (
   "I had this thing.",
   "That you could type up right.",
   "But it didn't sing.",
   "So I said goodnight."
   )
)
```

works in Python 2 but not in Python 3, where PowerShell claims a syntax error in the first line of the `print` statement.

Am I right that much of the difference between Python 2 and Python 3 concerns `print` statements? How would the above code look in Python 3?

Comment: You could try [Learn Python 3 the Hard Way](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/python3/), the updated version of the book for Python 3.

Comment: Having said that, your code sample works fine for me in Python 3.5. Do you have unclosed parenthesis before the `print`?

Comment: You were right. There was, indeed, an unclosed parenthesis before the print.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by an unclosed parenthesis in the preceding `print` statement.